# How do I queue inserts to create a bulk insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to change my application so that it does bulk inserts instead of individual ones to ease the load on my server. I am not sure the best way to go about this. Thoughts so far are:

1. Use a text file and write all the insert / update statements to this file and process it every 5 mins - I am not sure of the best way to handle this one. Would reading from one process (to create the bulk insert) cause issues when the main process is still trying to add more statements to it? Would I need to create a new file every 5 mins and delete it when its processed.
2. Store the inserts in a session and then just process them. Would this cause any problems with memory ect?

I am using PHP and MySQL with MyISAM tables. I am open to all ideas on the best way to handle this, I just know I need to stop doing single inserts / updates.

Thanks.

Comment: Where's this data coming from and how often? Also, how often does the DB *need* to be updated?

Comment: @Null - The data needs to be updated every 5 mins tops. There are about 100 inserts per second at busy times. It is basically logs from a script being used.

Comment: option 3: write data to temporary table which has no indexes at all (minimal write overhead), then transfer to the real table on a scheduled basis.

Comment: @Marc - That is still more overhead and slower than 1 bulk insert for the data.

Comment: @Person Who Deleted their comment- I haven't done any tests but bulk inserts "should" be faster shouldn't they? Bulk inserts will probably happen during peak times but I figured that this will still be less overhead than single ones spamming the MySQL server.

Comment: @webnoob Is that a fact or just a guess?

Comment: @webnoob - I think you just delay the problem, it still lock the table when bulk insert/bulk update took place

Comment: @ajreal - Is there a better way to handle this then?

Comment: @webnoob. You might want to take a look at `LOAD DATA`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: @Null - That will be perfect. Write to a file then just use that. Can you write it as an answer please.

Comment: @webnoob -- you need to explain what sort of logs generated by script, and how important of the data is that, because logs means to be logging into file in most cases. 100 insert per seconds is not a problem for MYSQL, BUT the update might NOT work if involved lots of rows, specify what sort of INSERT/UPDATE you are looking for, and the table schema as well, and how many server did you have?

Comment: Somebody else just did. But at any rate; Is a bulk insert faster than multiple inserts? Probably. But code performance can be tricky and our intuition can betray us. Always benchmark and test your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get data into the database is to use `load data infile` on a text file.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

You can also use bulk inserts of course, if you want them to queue behind selects, use a syntax like:

```
INSERT LOW PRIORITY INTO table1 (field1, field2) VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),...
or
INSERT DELAYED INTO .....
```

Note that `delayed` does not work with InnoDB. 
Also note that `low priority` is not recommended when using MyISAM.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should create a new file for each 5 minutes fro insert and update separately and remove the ones after processing.
2. For bulk insert

   1. You can use LOAD DATA INFILE with disabled keys on table.
   2. If you use innodb you should run all inserts in transaction for preventing flushing indexes on each query and use form with multiple VALUES(),(),().
   3. If you use MyIsam you should insert with DELAYED option. Also if you don't remove rows from table it's possible to have concurrent read/write.
3. For bulk updates you should use transaction because you will get the same effect.